# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (21,) and (22,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, graphics

I'm trying to make graphic from array, but the result keeps showing `ValueError`. What should I do?

This is my code:

```
# array bisection
array_list_iter_bisect = np.array(list_iter_bisect)
array_list_ea_bisect = np.array(list_ea_bisect)

# array false position
array_list_iter_falsepost = np.array(list_iter_falsepost)
array_list_ea_falsepost = np.array(list_ea_falsepost)

iter_max = 0
matrix_iter_count = [array_list_ea_bisect,array_list_iter_falsepost]
for arr_iter in matrix_iter_count:
    if (iter_max < arr_iter[-1]):
        iter_max = arr_iter[-1]

# Parameter for the constant function of Error Max
error_max = es
x_error_max = range(1, iter_max+1)
y_error_max = [error_max] * len(x_error_max)

# Plotting the graph 
plt.plot(list_iter_bisect, list_ea_bisect, c='blue')
plt.plot(list_iter_falsepost, list_ea_falsepost, c='green')
plt.plot(x_error_max, y_error_max, c='black')
plt.plot(x_error_max, y_error_max, c='black')
plt.annotate('εs', xy=(0, error_max), xytext=(-1, error_max), fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Iteration #')
plt.ylabel('εa (error)')
plt.title(f'εa method vs iteration Z-factor | T = {660}R | P = {3000} psia')
plt.legend(["Bisection", "False-Position"], bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, 1.15), ncol=2)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Should I pop the array?

Comment: Please be careful with case. `valueerror` and `ValueError` are different things, and that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the line where the error occurs and without knowing the content/size of list_iter_bisect, list_ea_bisect, list_iter_falsepost, list_ea_falsepost, it is

I think the error could be here:

```
plt.plot(x_error_max, y_error_max, c='black')
```

which carries the definitions:

```
x_error_max = range(1, iter_max+1)
y_error_max = [error_max] * len(x_error_max)
```

try to define x_error_max in the following way:

```
x_error_max = np.arange(1, iter_max+1)
```

either

```
x_error_max = range(1, iter_max)
```

I recommend not repeating the line:

```
plt.plot(x_error_max, y_error_max, c='black')
```

twice